# How to pass promoted form's QSpinBoxes values to MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, parameter-passing, getter-setter

In my project I promoted *Qt Designer form class* to `mainwindow.ui`. promoted ui I named as `doublerect.ui` and which containing two `QspinBoxes` one is `sb_rect_height` and other one is `sb_rect_width` . Now I need to pass those spinboex values to mainwindow.there for I created `getters` and `setters`. But when I access `getter` from `mainwindow` those values print as this **`0 This main weight  , 1072693248 This main height`** . So please tell me and give me a solution how can I access those spinboxes values from `mainwindow`.[This my complete code](https://github.com/sachithmw/47847976)

**doublerect.cpp**

```
#include "doublerect.h"
#include "ui_doublerect.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "qdebug.h"

DoubleRect::DoubleRect(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DoubleRect)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->sb_rect_height, static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
            this, &DoubleRect::setHeight);
    connect(ui->sb_rect_width, static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
            this, &DoubleRect::setWidth);
}

DoubleRect::~DoubleRect()
{
    delete ui;
}

int DoubleRect::getWidth() const
{
    return width;
}

void DoubleRect::setWidth(int value)
{
    width = value;
}

int DoubleRect::getHeight() const
{
    return height;
}

void DoubleRect::setHeight(int value)
{
    height = value;
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <QColorDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->widgethide->setVisible(true);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::addRect()
{

    DoubleRect *obj = new DoubleRect();
    int height = obj->getHeight();
    int width = obj->getWidth();
    qDebug()<< height <<"This main height";
    qDebug()<< width <<"This main width";

}

void MainWindow::on_btnRect_clicked()
{
    addRect();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods `setHeight` and `setWidth` of `DoubleRect` class should be in section - private slots.

```
public:
  explicit DoubleRect(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~DoubleRect();

  int getWidth() const;
  int getHeight() const;
public slots:

private slots:
  void setHeight(int value);
  void setWidth(int value);
```

**EDIT**

When `addRect` method is called, in constructor of `DoubleRect` you assign signal `valueChanged()` 
of SpinBox with your slots - `setHeight` and `setWidth`, then you want to print width and height using `qDebug()`,
but first you need to change value of spinbox in order to slots can be invoked - and width with height can be set.

You cannot create `obj` every time you call `addRect()` method. This object should be create only one time. 
Then signal-slots connection is made, and when values of spinbox are changed, your slots will be called setting height and width correctly.

**EDIT 2**
You can define `DoubleRect` object as member of `MainWindow`:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
  QGraphicsScene * scene;
  QGraphicsView * view;
  DoubleRect* obj;
};
```

create this object in ctor of MainWindow

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  //...
  obj = new DoubleRect();
}
```

now, when you change value of SpinBox, slots setWidth/setHeight will be called, and invoking 'addRect' method you should get correct values.

**EDIT 3**

I have downloaded your project, I use QT 4.8.4, after some modifications it works, so

[1] changes in *doublerect.cpp*

```
 DoubleRect::DoubleRect(QWidget *parent) :
 QWidget(parent),
 ui(new Ui::DoubleRect)
 {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // NEW LINES !!! 
    connect (ui->sb_rect_height, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setHeight(int)));
    connect (ui->sb_rect_width, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setWidth(int)));
 }
```

use connect function to make connection between SIGNAL - SLOT

[2] changes in *doublerect.h*

```
class DoubleRect : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit DoubleRect(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~DoubleRect();

  int getWidth() const;
  int getHeight() const;
 public slots:
 private slots:      // NEW LINES, these methods must be slots
   void setHeight(int value);
   void setWidth(int value);
 private:
    Ui::DoubleRect *ui;
    int width;
    int height;
 };
```

and the most important things, changes in *mainwindow.cpp*

```
void MainWindow::addRect()
{
  //DoubleRect *obj = new DoubleRect();  // don't create new object
  int height = ui->widgethide->getHeight();
  int width = ui->widgethide->getWidth();
  qDebug()<< height <<"This main height";
  qDebug()<< width <<"This main width";
}
```

you don't need to create `DoubleRect` object, this object exists already, pointer to instance of this object is `ui->widgethide`.

Comment: So what i need to do now.give me some complete sample code solution.please

Comment: I did so,now print as `0 This main height , 0 This main width` . please check my github project file and do some modifications. because I'm stack with this.please check it and help me to solve this

Comment: @Learner  read edit 3, after these modifications code works under QT 4.8.4

Comment: message was sent